# Lebesgue measure of a circular arc on the surface of the hypersphere

Tags: probability-distributions, geometric-probability

The following sub-problem came up in one of my research works:

Suppose that $U$ is a uniform random variable on the surface of the $d$-dimensional sphere with center at the origin and of radius $r$. Also, let $v$ be an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$. What is the exact value (or maybe a good approximation) of the following probability?

$$\mathbb{P}(v^\top U > c) $$

You may assume that $c$ is any real number less than the trivial Cauchy-Schwarz bound $r\|v\|$. Of course the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: \|x\|=r~,~v^\top x > c\}$ is a circular arc (portion) on the surface of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with radius $r$, so the problem essentially boils down to calculating the Lebesgue measure of this circular portion on the sphere, but it seems that I am not able to get an exact answer for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As soon as one realizes this is called a [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), it is easy to find the answer, for example, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Hyperspherical_cap) or at [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2238265/428180).